# GraphQL - Apollo printSchema error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'kind')

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo, graphql-js, apollo-federation

I am trying to use the `printSchema` function from Apollo to include @directives in the GQL Schema.

However it keeps showing this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'kind')
    at KnownDirectivesRule (node_modules\graphql\validation\rules\KnownDirectivesRule.js:43
:13)
    at \node_modules\graphql\validation\validate.js:90:12
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at validateSDL (\node_modules\graphql\validation\validate.js:89:24)
    at buildSchemaFromSDL (\node_modules\@apollo\federation\node_modules\@apollo\subgraph\di
st\schema-helper\buildSchemaFromSDL.js:143:47)
    at Object.buildSubgraphSchema (\node_modules\@apollo\federation\node_modules\@apollo\sub
graph\dist\buildSubgraphSchema.js:26:57)
    at file:///finalizeProcessFunction.js:34:37
    at SchemaBuilder.applyHooks (\node_modules\graphile-build\node8plus\SchemaBuilder.js:264
:20)
    at SchemaBuilder.buildSchema (\node_modules\graphile-build\node8plus\SchemaBuilder.js:34
0:33)
    at SchemaBuilder.watchSchema (\node_modules\graphile-build\node8plus\SchemaBuilder.js:40
8:34)
```

My schema is very long so I don't paste the whole file here, but basically it's just a normal GQL Schema that has multiple `type`, then `Query`, `Mutation` and `Subscription`.

The directives that I am adding is under `Subscription` called `@aws_subscribe`, it is use for AppSync subscription.

So the code that pops this error is this:

```
let federatedSchema = printSchema.buildSubgraphSchema(schema);
```

The schema type is `GraphQLSchema` and it looks like this:
[image]

What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you passing the schema in as a parsed document node, or as an unparsed string?

Comment: @phry As a `GraphQLSchema` type, the content has been updated in the question.

Comment: That looks like a very empty schema, how do you create that?

Comment: @phry It was auto generated by PostGraphile from my PostgreSQL table.

Comment: @SivvieLim Has your problem been fixed?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation here ([API Reference: @apollo/subgraph](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/using-federation/api/apollo-subgraph/) ), and here ( [Introspection query result to SDL](https://www.apollographql.com/blog/backend/schema-design/three-ways-to-represent-your-graphql-schema#introspection-query-result-to-sdl) ), makes it seem like your syntax is wrong. I think it's supposed to be like this: `printSchema(buildSubgraphSchema({schema: schema }))`

Did you try anything similar to that? I recommend also looking at this answer to a question on the Apollo community forum: [printschema with directives for uploading to Apollo studio managed federation](https://community.apollographql.com/t/printschema-with-directives-for-uploading-to-apollo-studio-managed-federation/2313/6)

Comment: Oh I decide to just append the directives using a lambda function to the AppSync. Thank you so much for your input though!